# What do I do if my predicted values are out of the dependent variable range?

Tags: regression, sas, beta-distribution

I have built a beta regression model with log link for predicting adherence. My dependent variable's range is 0 to 1.When I used a test set to calculate the predicted values with the parameter estimates from this model, the values were out of range (>1 and max was 2.3). 
Is it wrong if I scale them to 0 to 1 range? It does nt really alter the distribution graph much.

What should I do if the predicted values are out of range in general?

**Edit**: The Code

I am using proc glmmix (sas).

```
proc glimmix data=_exp0_.Beta_training; 
class gndr_cd medispan_drug_class_grp_desc ecom ; 
model days_adhered=norm_age gndr_cd drug_type norm_days_until_refill total_fills/ dist=beta solution link=log s; 
random residual; 
nloptions technique=quanew update=bfgs; 
run;
```

Comment: Did you use R and predict()? If so, did you use predict(model, type="response")? If that does not help could you post the code and perhaps share the data?

Comment: adding to first comment, if you really used beta regression for the prediction then a predicted value of 2.3 should be impossible, so you did something wrong (or something else than you thought you did!)

Comment: Please post your code. Something is wrong.

Comment: @Peter
Oh thanks. I am using proc glmmix (sas).


proc glimmix data=_exp0_.Beta_training;
class gndr_cd drug_class  ;
model days_adhered= age gndr_cd  drug_type days_until_refill total_fills/ dist=beta solution link=log s;
random residual; 
nloptions technique=quanew update=bfgs; 
run;